# How to download video from url into internal storage of phone in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am playing a video in my app from the URL. I need to download that video into internal storage of phone. How can I achieve this. Is there any way. I am new to flutter?

Answer (score 2):

You can download video using the following code ....

```js
static var httpClient = HttpClient();

Future<File> downloadFile(String url1, String filename) async {
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url1));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }
```

Comment: any plugins required?

Comment: `path_provider`, `http`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you

```
downloadVideo()
  { var url = "Your url";
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;

  if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
  }
    var tempPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
try {

  var res = await http.get(
    '$url',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': _userDataController.userDataModel.token,//if authorization is not required then remove this line
    },
  );

  filePath = tempPath + '/Video1.mp4';//use you own video format


} catch (e) {

  print(e);
}}
```

you have to use [permission_handler: ^8.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) & [http: ^0.13.3](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [path_provider: ^2.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)